# System variable for Microsoft SDKs

Tags: msbuild, environment-variables, strongname, system-variable

Similar to the %WINDIR% system variable which we have for the Windows directory, do we have any system variable which points to the latest version of the Microsoft SDK folder, so that I can access the sn.exe in my Build script?

Answer (score 5):

I am running MSBuild 4.0 and in my proj file ToolsVersion is set to 4.0. The variable SDK40ToolsPath points to where the .NET 4.0 tools are installed. SDK35ToolsPath points to where the .NET 3.5 tools are installed.

MSBuild reads these variables, base on the value of ToolsVersion, from the registry at: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0.